# libreadline.so.6 missing - Can not access R via command line after installation

Tags: r

I did put R on path using the `.bashrc` file. And yet, I do not have access to R through the command line. I have nevertheless no issues with RStudio. When I check for the R location with `which R`, I get `/home/myself/anaconda3/bin/R`. I have Ubuntu 20.04. The error message that I get is `/home/myself/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I have version `R version 4.1.3` which I have installed recently. Working in JupyterLab in anaconda, I installed again R in a conda environement. Unfortunately, I get inside the conda environment the same error message.
When I try to install the missing package, I get the message:`libreadline6 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable`.

I also tried to install libreadline with conda, `conda install -c conda-forge m2-libreadline` (as suggested on the anaconda site) as well as `conda install -n base -c conda-forge libreadline.so.6`. The message I get is: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- libreadline.so.6
- m2-libreadline`

I will highly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the answers here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168787/libreadline-so-6-issue-in-ubuntu-18-04
Basically, you need to install libreadline.so.6 or create a symlink from the version of libreadline you have to this libreadline.so.6.

Comment: Yes I did. It did not help.